# Run a local script remotely via ssh while passing arguements

Tags: perl, ssh

I am using this command fine:

```
ssh user@ip 'bash -s' -- < /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ssh_mem.sh
```

I don't like the results of that script so want to use a perl script instead and use this:

```
ssh user@ip 'perl -s' -- < /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.pl

check_mem.pl v1.0 - Nagios Plugin

usage:
  check_mem.pl -<f|u> -w <warnlevel> -c <critlevel>

options:
 -f           Check FREE memory
 -u           Check USED memory
 -C           Count OS caches as FREE memory
 -w PERCENT   Percent free/used when to warn
 -c PERCENT   Percent free/used when critical
```

As you can see, I get proper feedback from the script.  I want to pass it the -f, -w and -c variables but get errors when trying to do that.

Comment: What are the errors?  I suspect you are not quoting the path to the script and your arguments to be fed to ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[man perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) says:

```
Upon startup, Perl looks for your program in one of the following places
...
3. Passed in implicitly via standard input.  This works only if there are 
   no filename arguments--to pass arguments to a STDIN-read program you must
   explicitly specify a "-" for the program name.
```

So, you can use this:

```
ssh user@ip 'perl - -f -u -C' -- < /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.pl
```

The arguments after the - are passed to the script you are running.

You don't need the -s argument - I assume you copied that from your original bash implementation, but -s has a different meaning for perl.